# Pandas dataframe cell divided by subtotals

Tags: pandas, dataframe, percentage

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

[image]

My end goal is to calculate the percent of each purpose and for each origin

[image]

So the final table should look this:

[image]

Any assistance or direction will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `df.dropna(how='any').pop('values')` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to drop the unwanted rows

```
i = df[(df.Origin == 'total origin')].index
df = df.drop(i)
```

And this to drop the Values column

```
df = df.drop(columns='Values')
```